# Routing in Codeigniter (:any) gives me strange results

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-routing

Here i'm using below routing config

```
$route['controllername/(:any)'] = "controllername/index/$1";
```

this is working well for me, but i want to use other methods in the same controller.
for that i'm using below route

```
$route['controllername/search'] = "controllername/search";
```

this is also working fine, but i want pass parameters to this method.
Here if i'm passing parameters but it is calling **index** method

i want to use both of above routes, i have tried with below route also but same result

```
$route['controllername/search/(:any)'] = "controllername/search/$1";
```

could anyone give any suggestions?
Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.Do it like this for routing multiple functions in same controller :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "controller_name";
$route['index/(:any)'] = "controller_name/index/$1";
$route['search/(:any)'] = "controller_name/search/$1";
```

Let me know if you find any issues or doubts.

Answer (score 0):

@user4039421

change your roouting rules position like below

```
$route['controllername/search/(:any)'] = "controllername/search/$1";
$route['controllername/search'] = "controllername/search";
$route['controllername/(:any)'] = "controllername/index/$1";
```